# How to pull information from an object from an api in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have some API endpoints from which I'm trying to pull some informations.
I was wondering if there is a way to pull the information from an object as I'm trying to do with the first two? When I try the following approach I get all the infos I need from the first 2 endpoints but when it comes to the third, which is an object I get something like <object object 0x10a427f70>.

````
import requests
import csv
import unicodedata
import getpass


url = 'https://url.com/api/v2/products.json'

user = '...'
pwd = '...'

csvfile = 'products.csv'

output_1 = []
output_1.append("id")
output_2 = []
output_2.append("created_at")
output_3 = []
output_3.append("details")
while url:
  
    user = '...'
    pwd = '...'
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd))
    data = response.json()
    for product in data ['products']:
            product_id = product['id']
            decode_1 = int(product_id)
            output_1.append(decode_1)
    for product in data ['products']:
            created_at = product['created_at']
            decode_2 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', created_at).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
            output_2.append(decode_2)
    for product in data ['products']:
            details = product['details']
            decode_3 = object()
            output_3.append(decode_3)
    print(data['next_page'])
    url = 'https://url.com/api/v2/products.json' and data['next_page']
    
   
    
print("products:")
print(len(output_1))
     

        # Write to a csv file
with open(csvfile, 'w') as fp:
      writer = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
      writer.writerow([output_1])
      writer.writerow([output_2])
      writer.writerow([output_3]) 
    ```
````

Comment: An "Object" in python doesn't really represent anything. and by definition is empty. Check here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_object.asp . I am still unsure however what you are trying to do exactly and what the issue is/where it is. Can you add more details please?

Comment: what is the type of that object?

Comment: by looking at the structure I believe this is an array of objects.
"details" :{
"detail1": "ipsum detail",
"detail2": 2123,
"detail3":"ipsum ipsum details"}

Comment: I guess I could list them.
...for product in data ['products']:
            details = product['details']
            decode_3 = list(details)....

Comment: I would `pprint.pprint(data, indent=4)` to see what I'm actually getting for the data, and then figure out what I want do with the data I'm getting. As stated by Zaid, you're now just assigning an empty object to `decode_3`, so this is working exactly as *intended* (although perhaps not as you *expect*). Note that the response seems to be a JSON, so read up on how to deal with that (basically list of dict items normally)